# I can't find my libs in jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, gradle

I am making a simple Desktop application in java, Build using gradle.I have added log4j jar into my application. App runs in eclipse. But when I run it in my terminal using `java -jar xxx.jar` it not recognize the log4j. Then I extract my jar file and check is there any log4j.jar files. But I can not find it. I know There is a problem with my build.gradle file. I tried to find it through Internet, But still can not. Any body can help me? How should I write the code to copy libs into my jar file ?

Comment: so when you are deploying it, maybe it is not being added to your jar?

Comment: Yep, log4j.jar not in my extracted jar. How can I add them ? Not only log4j.jar some other jar files also.

Comment: put it in your lib folder , so in eclipse `right click --> add  to buildpath`

Comment: @MostafaJamareh His issue is with running it from command line.

Comment: start by reading http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Comment: In eclipse my app is ruining. Cause I have added them in my build.gradle file as dependencies. But in jar ?

Comment: ok. I will go through it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to these links for the issue http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_add_jars_into_a_jar
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_you_add_jar_libraries_to_your_build